# Checking the wave key in LWJGL

Tags: keyboard, key, lwjgl, wave

How do I check the key "~" in LWJGL? I tried typeing "Keyboard.KEY_WAVE" but that didn't work. Any ideas? Also I'm using Slick2D with it, does that have support for the key?

Answer (score 1):

As seen in this [link](http://slick.javaunlimited.net/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=5417), The key you are looking for is called "Keyboard.KEY_GRAVE", so yes, it does indeed have support for that key.